# События NetworkManager

Tags: unity3d

Как отследить события в NetworkManager? Например он запускает сцену автоматически , когда нажимаешь host, - где можно прописать в скрипт необходимые проверки, например на кол-во игроков? А так же как определить какие действия будут выполнены при подключении клиента/создании  хоста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну для этого можно наследоваться от класса `NetworkManager` и в соответствующих виртуальных методах начинающихся с `On` дополнить необходимое поведение (например `OnStartHost`, OnClientConnected` и т.п.). Воспользуйтесь справкой и переводчиком, в принципе там все понятно [NetworkManager Script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, я верно понимаю, что например именно метод StartHost вызывается через соответствующую кнопку в NetworkHUD?

Comment: Полагаю что да) в Примерах именно так запускают хост)